# Translating either a word or sentence into pig latin

Tags: java

so basically the problem I have about this problem is that I am not allowed to use Stringbuilder, arrays, or String.split() to create this program. I am completely stumped to do this, because if I could use these ways to solve the program, I wouldn't be here.

As for the actual program:
What is required is to take in a word or sentence that recognizes the first vowel and takes the characters that come before it and places it after the vowel and other characters by separating it with "-(characters before vowel)ay". In other word it translates the string into pig latin in such fasion:

> The deepest shade

Translates into:

> e-Thay eepest-day ade-shay

This is what I have so far, keep in mind I am getting a String out of bounds error on line 12 from my if statement because for some reason it crashes after detected a space in between words. I also have no idea how to incorporate a way to have this program handle just a single word and sentences.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String word = "", temp = "", secondTemp = "", beforeVowel = "", translation = "";
    int start = 0, stop = 0, counter = 0;
    char a = 'a', e = 'e', charI = 'i', o = 'o', u = 'u';
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a word or sentence to translate it into Pig Latin");
    word = input.next();
    while(input.hasNext()) {
        if(!(word.charAt(stop) == ' ')) {
            stop++;
        }
        else {
            temp = word.substring(start, stop);
            start = stop;
            for(int i = 0; i<temp.length(); i++) {
                if(temp.charAt(i) == a || temp.charAt(i) == e || temp.charAt(i) == charI || temp.charAt(i) == o || temp.charAt(i) == u) {
                    secondTemp = temp.substring(0, i);
                    translation = temp.substring(i-1) + "-" + secondTemp + "ay";
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(translation);
    }
}
```

I have made some changes to improve my code and have gotten to the point where I can translate the first word of the string, yet my code will completely disregard the rest of the words in the string.

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
  String word = "", temp = "", secondTemp = "", beforeVowel = "", translation = "";
    int start = 0, stop = 0, counter = 0;
    char a = 'a', e = 'e', charI = 'i', o = 'o', u = 'u';
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a word or sentence to translate it into Pig Latin");
    word = input.next();
    while(input.hasNext()) {
            for(int i = 0; i<word.length(); i++) {
                if(word.charAt(i) == a || word.charAt(i) == e || word.charAt(i) == charI || word.charAt(i) == o || word.charAt(i) == u) {
                    secondTemp = word.substring(0, i);
                    translation += word.substring(i) + "-" + secondTemp + "ay";
                }
            }
            break;
        }

        System.out.println(translation);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`input.next()` already provides you the next word, so I don't think you have to go looking around for whitespace. This looks like homework, so perhaps it would be best not to give you the full answer yet, but your way of doing it is pretty close.

Because `input.next()` provides the next word, I completely got rid of the branching here. Words don't have whitespace.

```
    if(!(word.charAt(stop) == ' ')) {
        stop++;
    }
    else {
        temp = word.substring(start, stop);
        start = stop;
```

and, as `hasNext()` returns `false` for the last element, the last element will not be processed, so I changed the loop to something like this:

```
for (word = input.next(); input != null; word = input.next()) {
```

(`input.next()` returns `null` when there is no input left)

This line is has an off-by-one error:

```
translation = temp.substring(i-1) + "-" + secondTemp + "ay";
```

And you need to `break` out of this loop right after, otherwise it'll go to the next vowel and discard the translation we found.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I took into consideration what you said and have made some strides. I can only seem to convert one word into pig latin even though I have multiple words. I changed the substring i-1 to just i. I think this is the cause of the problem... Not sure where to go from there

Comment: Ah. Had a look at your new code. It has two problems: You have two loops that are nested. The `break` I recommended is placed in the outer loop, rather than the inner loop. break takes you right out of the loop it's placed in, which in this case is the outer loop. The second problem is the `while` loop, which tests for `hasNext()`. When you encounter the last word, `hasNext()` will be `false`, and the final word will not be processed. Try with the `for`-loop in my answer. (Will update my answer with the reason I changed the loop.)